# how to print the latest date for every unique values of 1st column in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
NY2001 May 11 2014
NY2001 May 9 2014
NY2011 Jun 12 2014
NY2019 Jun 19 2014
NY2019 Jun 21 2014
```

how to print the latest date for every unique values of 1st column in Linux bash.

Comment: What do you mean by 'print the latest date for every unique values of 1st column'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while read p q; do echo "$p "$(date -d "$q" '+%s'); done < file| awk '
   !($1 in a) || a[$1]<$2{a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) {
         printf "%s ", i; system("date \"+%d %b %Y\" -d @" a[i])}}'
NY2019 21 Jun 2014
NY2001 11 May 2014
NY2011 12 Jun 2014
```